# Reconstuct a video in exact same fps and bitrate as it was split

Tags: ffmpeg

This is how I had split into frames(jpg),

```
ffmpeg -i myvid.mp4 frame%05d.jpg -hide_banner
```

This is how I am trying to reconstruct(mp4),

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i frame%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p myvid_recons.mp4
```

But I am finding the recombined video is slow by a factor of 150x.
I tries to expremint with fps optiob but found no improvement.

Comment: What is the frame rate of the input? Posting the complete log from commands (without `-hide_banner`) help us avoid having to ask for more info and will result in faster answers. Using the same bitrate is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have told it to be slow: `-r 1/5` You have forced the input to be `1/5` Frames Per Second. Remove this option from your command line.

Comment: Keep in mind that the default for the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) is `-framerate 25`.